# Xcode 3.0 debugger keeps skipping breakpoints.

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging

I'm using Xcode 3.0 on a PowerBook G4. I needed to test some code to see how it runs on a big endian host. I already had it set up to go so got it out to test.

I first created an empty project and added my binary as a custom executable as well as loading in some source files. This seemed to be working fine. The code is a C++ terminal application and I had already setup a Makefile with CMake.

In the beginning I set up some breakpoints and started up the debugger. And it worked well. Stopping at my breakpoints. But then something happened that I don't know what and it started ignoring them.

I setup a new project like before and started from scratch again. Loaded the debugger. And once again it ignored them!

So then I managed to get CMake (2.8.12) to generate an Xcode project file. Which didn't go too easy as it didn't know what compiler I had. Looks like I stumbled onto another bug there. I eventually got past it by going between the CMake GUI and terminal.

I then closed all windows in Xcode and quit it. I then opened up the new project to start afresh. I set up some new breakpoints and loaded up the debugger. The code fell through again but then I realised I didn't set any arguments. So I did that and tried again. It ran through again! I looked up how to reset Xcode prefs and did so. Try again and it keeps ignoring my breakpoints!

I know it's kinda bad to setup an account to ask a question. And I hate to do that. But I'm really over this and don't know what is wrong with it. I've Googled for answers, got some hits here, and tried suggestions like disabling lazy symbols, making sure strip doesn't kill debug symbols and other symbol stuff but none has any affect. I've wasted hours trying to fix it instead of testing code I need too.

What's disconcerting is that no source is loading into the [GDB] debugger either. I actually forced it to stop by doing an implicit read from location zero in my source. And even this wasn't right. It didn't even load up the source but just gave me a disassembly. Even though I had it set to show only source. There's something wrong with it. :-?

Well thanks for any help. I don't know if I'm getting old or what. But this is getting as annoying as a small hidden bug in code that brings the whole house down! ;-)

Comment: Being old doesn't mean you should have unreasonable expectations. You are using an IDE that is five generations old, on an obsolete architecture and you only have 1 issue, and find it annoying?

Comment: No I have other issues but this is the show stopper. Perhaps it is just an OSX thing. On Linux I would be done by now.

Comment: I bet the Linux you are using isn't as old as the OS X you are using. If at all possible, copy the code to a machine that supports Xcode 8, and let the compiler help you with your issues.

Comment: Setting up an account isn't bad at all. It's what most people here do. We just hope you'll stick around ;).

Comment: Yes Linux would be newer. And unlike OSX the usual configure/make/install tends to work with the right depends installed and pre-compiled.

Funny as it sounds, using a "popular" CPU won't help me, because I need a "WYSIWYG" CPU. One that won't reverse words coming in and out, but loads and stores them exactly as they are in memory. Can running XCode 8 help to "patch" the project file so it works again on XCode 3? :-)

Comment: So I tried to rebuild the project. Wiped my binaries and compiled again. Didn't see any change. I had a few other binaries lying around from before but these weren't part of the project I made so didn't think it would affect it. So I decided to have one last go at it before looking at using PPC Linux.

Comment: I wiped all the build files sans the source files and generated a build project again from CMake. I then loaded this into XCode and set it all up again. I attempt to set a breakpoint and load up the debugger. And it starts to work once again! I don't know what was stopping it but I'm happy it works now. I noticed it tends to be a bit slow. Don't know if this is because the IDE isn't exactly integrated and wraps a GUI over GDB. But I did source level debugging on my way slower Amiga A1200 and it was way faster. LOL. :-D